# Remove hashtags from a URL but still jump to the element

Tags: jquery, html, hashtag

Here's my predicament. I have three links from one page that go to another one and take the visitor to its respective DIV id:

```
www.mysite.com/#about
www.mysite.com/#gallery
www.mysite.com/#help
```

It's working fine, but I really need to remove the trailing hashtags from the URL or it messes with a jquery gallery slider. Is this possible? I've seen others asking similar questions but they don't seem to be navigating to a new page.

What I am looking for is a way for a visitor to click on the link (e.g., `www.mysite.com/#about`) and be taken to that page (and respective element) but have the browser trim off the `#about` and just report `www.mysite.com`.

Jquery, PHP, javascript, I don't care what really.

I was thinking another alternative would be to take the user to www.mysite.com and then apply the hashtag afterwards. Is this at all possible? Just so they are taken to the element but the url in the browser doesn't reflect the hashtag.

PS: I'm no coder so if there is a bit of code that can do this, can you guys be really clear on how to implement?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's called a "fragment identifier", not a hashtag. It refers to a fragment of the document.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `history api`.

First, we check if there's a state in the stack. Whatever the state is will be the most recent item we pushed into the stack.

We assume that the `id` of the element is the same as the `hash`. We use it as a selector on our `div` and get that divs `offset().top`.

```
if(history.state){  
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('div[id='+history.state.element+']').offset().top); 
}
```

Now let's take a look at the click function. We prevent the default behavior and store the href in a variable (because we'll use it a few times). We push a state into the stack. The `element` key has a value of `whatever comes after the hash tag`. We also provide some other information about the stacked state. When we're done, we simply redirect the page location to the element's location `without` the hash tag.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var ele =  $(this).prop('href');
    window.history.pushState({'element' : ele.split('#')[1]}, ele, ele.split('#')[0]);

    window.location = ele.split('#')[0]; 
});
```

Now when the next page loads, the history wlil have a state, which will be the most recent stack pushed. This will emulate the behavior you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately, it didn't work. No errors, no nothing. Browser still leaves in the fragment id as per normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice solution in jQuery:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Thanks for the post, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I don't need to scroll anywhere on a page (I'm already doing that). I need to make sure that when I send a visitor to a new page, that the URL doesn't carry the hashtag.