# Can't remove hashtag from url after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I tried almost every solution i found from this website and from other but with no success.
What i am doing is rotating a button using CSS3 animation.
I am doing this by having the button linked(using "a" element) and then enabling the animation using the pseudo element :target(almost equal to onclick event works in this case).

My problem is that when i click to the button at the first time a hash-tag(#btnq1 in my case) is being added to the URL.

Now, the actual problem, is that i cannot remove this hash-tag when i reload the whole page or if i want to click to that button one more time and re-run the animation.
I tried solutions from some Stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120053/remove-hashtags-from-a-url-but-still-jump-to-the-element) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268075/remove-hashtag-from-url) but didn't got any good result.

See below my code:

You can ignore the initial phase of the animation named q1.
HTML code:

```
<header>
<div id="title">
Just a title
</div>
</header>

<main>
Not important text

<div id="q1">
<div class="q1once">
<a href="#btnq1"><button type="button" name="" value="" id="btnq1">Click to rotate</button></a>
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

CSS code:

```
#q1{
    height:100%;
    }

.q1once{
    width:20%;
    height:15%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%;
    animation-name:q1;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-duration:1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    }

#btnq1:target{
    animation-name:q1leave;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-duration:4s;      
    }

@keyframes q1{
50%{
    transform:translate(440%) scaleX(3);
    }
100%{
    transform:translate(450%) scale(1.5,2);
    }
}
@keyframes q1leave{
    0%{transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
        }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
        transform:rotate(360deg);
        }
```

}

You can check my [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRgnL/3/) as well.

Adding `window.location.hash=''` on load of the page is a good partial solution because it removes the hashtag when i reload the page. However, it doesn't remove the hashtag after i click at the button at the first time. I want this to happen in order to be able to rotate the button more than once.

Comment: You've missed adding your JSFiddle?

Comment: @IzaazYunus Just added it. Although, it's the same as the code shown above.

Comment: Your code just renders text. I don't see a link. Is it just me?

Comment: @Mike Button is being used as a "link" in order to enable animation using :target pseudo element. You can check that is working using the jsfiddle

Comment: I'm not sure why you put the hashtag in the link in the first place, but you must have a good reason. Maybe [this could help](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: @climbinghobo My best answer is that this worked for me so far..

Comment: i don't see any animations in your fiddle

Comment: Your fiddle just shows two lines of plain text

Comment: @kennypu there is a delay of 3 seconds to the animation. just wait few

Comment: i've had it open for a while, all i see is: `To watch a movie or not
fwe34`

Comment: @climbinghobo I am trying to use your link but no success so far. Is this working in all browers? Can you provide a jsfiddle or full code using your solution?

Comment: @kennypu Please check jsfiddle again now

Comment: samething, are you testing to make sure it works? from inspect element, the button is way off to the left and is unclickable.

Comment: @kennypu Just updated jsfiddle for the last time to be sure you will be able to see it working properly. Please re-check

Comment: there's the problem, `@keyframes` is supported only IE10, firefox, and opera. you need the -webkit prefix for chrome and safari

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51144/discussion-between-dchris-and-kennypu)

Comment: if we were to answer the title, you can just run `window.location.hash=''` on load of the page

Comment: @kennypu 
i am using only firefox for my testing. i don't think this is the issue

Comment: @kennypu Can you show example where window.location.hash='' is working? I'm trying to use it but it doesn't work

Comment: @kennypu Now, it's working for page load. How can i make it work when i want the button to rotate again?

Comment: @kennypu You can add your comment as an answer but i prefer to have an answer for rotating the button more than once as well. This is more important for me

Comment: Actually you can change the displayed url to whatever you want with `history.pushState` or `replaceState`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 How can i do this without loading the page?

Comment: @Dchris - http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/u7Hqh/show

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Can you fix my jsfiddle? I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below solved my issue:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    history.replaceState ("", document.title, e.originalEvent.oldURL);
});
```

Found from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312006/remove-hashtag-from-url).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#btnq1').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // your action
});
```

Hashtags will not be added anymore

Comment: what //your action should have?

Answer (score -1):

To clear the hash on page load, you can add:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() { window.location.hash = ''; };
</script>
```

now, if you also want to clear it when the button is clicked, we can just add an onclick event to the button:

```
<a href="#btnq1" onclick="window.location.hash = ''">...
```

Comment: Down vote is not for me. For when the button is clicked is not working properly. It is remove the hash-tag only every 3 times that i click the button. On that moment it seems that page is forced to reload for some reason

Comment: @Dchris try putting the event on the `<button>` instead