# Remove hashtag(#) from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hashtag

I want hash-tags to be removed from URL after they are used.
For example, when i click on the link below:

```
<a href="#btnq1"><button type="button" name="" value="" id="btnq1">Just a button</button></a>
```

I want the hash-tag #btnq1 that appears to the URL of the page to be removed just after the action on this link happens.
I tried the below jquery code with no success:

```
$('#btnq1').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // your action
});
```

And even if this works, then how do i implement it to work for every hash tag that is added to the URL?
I would like to solve it using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026223/removing-hash-from-url

Comment: i've picked up a wrong question.

Comment: @user3348022 I don't see a solution to your possible duplicate.. I would be glad if you can show me..

Comment: Why do you have a link there? It is invalid, will break things in some browsers, and you are binding your click event to a button.

Comment: Having a button inside an anchor. http://validator.w3.org/ is a useful tool.

Comment: No, it isn't. HTML 5 expressly forbids it.

Comment: Content Model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant. — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element (a button, something designed to be clicked on, is interactive content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try that:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    history.replaceState ("", document.title, e.originalEvent.oldURL);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first add a class to your a tag that you want this behavior for, or a html 5 data- attribute.  Then your link becomes;

```
<a href="#btnq1" class="remove-hash"><button>Button</button></a>

$('body').on('click', ".remove-hash", function(e){
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Comment: when the above should be triggered? on page load? i tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: the . was missing from .remove-hash.

Comment: This is a good solution. Work with any element of ID or Class.