# remove hash from url smoothscroll.js

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem in a one page scrolling template that used a plagin (smoothscroll.js)
i try to remove hash from url after user click on link but unfortunatly i cant do it.for example

About Us

url take the hush and target(section2) like this `http://localhost/template/#section2`
how can i remove #section2 form the url

here is the code

```
var linkHandler = function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();

if (location.hash !== this.hash) window.history.pushState(null, null, this.hash);
// using the history api to solve issue #1 - back doesn't work
// most browser don't update :target when the history api is used:
// THIS IS A BUG FROM THE BROWSERS.
// change the scrolling duration in this call
smoothScroll(document.getElementById(this.hash.substring(1)), 1000, function(el) {
    location.replace('#' + el.id);
    // this will cause the :target to be activated.
});
```

}

Comment: if any one can help me please?

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312006/remove-hashtag-from-url will help.

Answer (score 0):

remove section2 from URL:

```
location.hash = '';
```

## edit

not sure why that's not working, but here's another, less efficient way:

```
location.href = location.href.split('#')[0];
```

Comment: after i added this at the end of function then it remove it but once scroll finish it appear again.

Comment: can you put your code into jsfiddle or codepen? that would make it much easier to help.

Comment: dear Todd here is the plagin if it is possible please check it. https://github.com/alicelieutier/smoothScroll