# How to remove certain part from url when page is refreshed?

Tags: jquery

In my HTML page i have got a ul class with two li tags , each one pointing to each table as shown below

```
     <li class='default'><a href="#one">Data</a></li>
     <li><a href="#two">Chart</a></li>


  <table id="one" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">  
  </table>
  <table id="two" class="tab-content-1 table table-striped">                        
  </table>
```

When clicked on the li tag the url looks this way

```
......./index.html#one

OR

......./index.html#two
```

So now when user presses F5 (reloads the page )

how to remove `#one` or `#two` from the URL ??

so that it looks as

```
......./index.html
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/29/

Could you please let me know how to resolve the issue ??

thanks in advance .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove hashtag(#) from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312006/remove-hashtag-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data-*` attribute to set `id` of element to show, hide , which should not change `location.href` to include hash when `a` element clicked

html

```
    <li class='default'><a data-href="#one">Data</a></li>
    <li><a data-href="#two">Chart</a></li>
```

css

```
li a:hover {
  cursor:pointer;   
}
```

js

```
var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("data-href");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jq4f69cz/32/